# jQuery Simpletip plugin to use the title attribute

Tags: jquery, simpletip

How can you make the [SimpleTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/) plugin use each element's `title` attribute for the tooltip text when you're applying it to a group of elements?

```
$('td[title]').simpletip({
    content : << this element's title attribute >>
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```
$('td[title]').each(function() {
    $(this).simpletip({
        content : $(this).attr('title')
    });
});
```

Comment: Ouch!  Beaten by 38 seconds!  With (almost) the exact same code, too.  Mine doesn't have a syntax error, though.  ;P

Comment: ill vote for yours if you vote for mine haha.  anyways, i was missing the ; at first too.  i thought "this guy stole my post, typo and all!"  ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('td[title]').each(function() {
    $(this).simpletip({
        content : $(this).attr('title')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack to do it:

In the Simpletip source code, around line 25:

```
// change this line:
.html(conf.content)
// to this
.html(conf.content ? conf.content : elem.attr('title'))
```

and then when you call the simpletip function:

```
$('td[title]').simpletip({
    content: false
});
```

Yep, it's a bit hacky, but it works.