# HTML A tag title formatting

Tags: html, title

I was wondering if it is possible to display the title from an A tag reference, which comes up as a pop-up in your browser, if anyone know of any libraries to make this pop-up much nicer and have the ability to format the content?

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).

Answer (score 1):

**[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/)** is a powerful jQuery tooltip option which allows Images, Videos, Thumbnails, etc within the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the tool tip itself, but you could use jQuery to create a div on the a:hover event, and style the div as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SimpleTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/) jQuery plugin for this.

There is more information over at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661140/jquery-simpletip-plugin-to-use-the-title-attribute) on how to use this with the title attribute.

**UPDATE**

SimpleTip has now been superseeded by [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible.  Not all browsers display a tooltip for anchor tags.  I suggest using JavaScript for this behavior:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip

Answer (score 0):

There's no pure HTML way to do this. Some browsers don't even show the title attribute.

Your best option would be to use one of the numerous Javascript libraries.

For jQuery: [25 Useful jQuery Tooltip Plugins and Tutorials](http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/)

For Prototype there aren't so many but [Prototip](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/) is promising.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt that's possible... yet. Why not roll your own on a hover event using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

By default title will be just a string, You can use any JS Plugins to make it look pretty. I guess you are not using any JS libraries as such, if using just javascript, here is a good one to work with [DHTML javascript tooltip](http://www.walterzorn.com/tooltip/tooltip_e.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I did some playing and finally came up with using [overLIB](http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib/), see my [blog](http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/post/2010/01/13/Simple-popups-or-hover-overs.aspx) for full details